# I can not compile the Xcode library with C++

Tags: c++, xcode, makefile, cmake, linker

the problem is that I need to compile the library with the makefile on macos which was compiled before in windows, the library was tested on Ubuntu (there it worked in contrast to the macOS (compiled)) When I add the makefile to xcodeporject, and try to build this project I get this error[Xcode building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Pnw.jpg)

so I can't build this library in Xcode with this makefile.
But if I trying this with the help of terminal ( have the same source files , same directories , same make file )
it is building , I don't know actually how , but it works,but when I start running tests ( also in terminal ) 
it gives me this 
[test running terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1euLC.png)
I'm new in compiling for macOS and in makefiles , idk whats going on, help please!

here is the text of errors in Xcode
 : `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
  "_xmlCheckVersion", referenced from:
      ADA::GCGxmlIO::OpenImpl(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, ADA::GCGFile&) in GCGxmlIO.o
      ADA::GCGxmlIO::SaveImpl(ADA::GCGxmlIO::IDeferredOstream*, ADA::GCGFile const&) in GCGxmlIO.o
  "_xmlDocGetRootElement", referenced from:
      ADA::GCGxmlIO::OpenImpl(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, ADA::GCGFile&) in GCGxmlIO.o
  "_xmlFree", referenced from:`

and the terminal error while running tests :
   `MacBook-Pro-Artem:gcc artem$ g++ -m32 -g -pipe -O3 -DNDEBUG -I../../../src -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -o ../../bin/common-wdi/apaEncode.xcodeproj ../../bin/common-wdi/obj/PDFAPI/apaEncode/encode.o ../../../bin/common-wdi/lib/PDFAPI.a ../../../bin/common-wdi/lib/ELib.a -lz`

```
'Undefined symbols for architecture i386:'
APA::PDPage::PAGE_SIZE_LETTER", referenced from:
APA::PDPageTree::NewPage(unsigned long) in PDFAPI.a(PDPageTree.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Please post the **text** of error messages and output.  Firewalls are preventing me from accessing your links.  Also, text scales better with mobile devices and large screens.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews may  be I can somehow use cmake to generate makefile , but I don't know how , because I have a lot of source code and dependencies, also this library is using libxml library

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I think the problem is int the make file that building project , especially in this line of code g++ -m32 -g -pipe -O3 -DNDEBUG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it already , the problem was in dependencies and in source code